# "Fundamentalrelation of Resonance Fluorescence" - How can it be?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-optics, fluorescence

In my quantum optics lecture, I was given the formula:
$$
\vec{d}_{eg} \hat{\vec{E}}^{(+)} = \frac{i \kappa \hbar}{2} | g \rangle \langle e |
$$
Here, $\vec{d}_{eg} = \langle e | \hat{\vec{d}} | g \rangle $ is the dipole matrix element of the dipole operator $\hat{\vec{d}}$, acting solely on the "atom" part of the Hilbert space, spanned by $|e \rangle$ and $| g \rangle$. $\hat{\vec{E}}^{(+)}$ acts solely on the field part of the Hilbert space. This formula is derived making some assumptions on the frequency of the fields (resonant fields, and the rotating wave approximation for interactions with the atom), and only holds if it acts on a state that evolved from the starting state $|0\rangle | g \rangle$. It is also derived in Mollow's paper [on resonant scattering](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235553304_Pure-state_analysis_of_resonant_light_scattering_Radiative_damping_saturation_and_multiphoton_effects), formula 3.21 (page 12). My professor introduced it as "Fundamental Relation of resonance fluorescence", I don't know if there is an other official name.

What I don't understand (and Mollow doesn't make comments on this issue): On the right side, I have an operator, acting solely on the EM-Field-Part of the hilbert space (for example, for only one mode, $\hat{\vec{E}}^{(+)} = \vec{c} * \hat{a}$, while on the other side, $| g \rangle \langle e |$ acts solely on the Atom-part of the hilbert space. How can there be equality?

Comment: seems like semiclassical approximation is invoked

Comment: It is used to calculate the time dependency of the state that the operators act uppon, but the operators, as I stated them, are certainly meant to be operators (especially the EM-Field Operator).

Comment: If no semiclassical assumption is involved, then even if you do rotating wave approximation, certainly $\hat{\vec{E}}_{}^\dagger.{\hat{n}}$ is missing on the right side.

Comment: Well .. no. There isn't missing anything. I stated the formula as it was given to me, and also as it is stated in mollows paper.

Comment: Can you mention which page of the paper Mollow writes down the equation you have given above. I am not able to find.

Comment: I had allready edited the formula, but I can give a page as well. It's page 12

Comment: I don't understand all the details of Mollow's discussion. But might it be simply that, since this is a non-Hermitian approximation to the true Hamiltonian, the photon number is not conserved (while the atomic dynamics remain approximately correct)?